# $V$ finite-dimensional vector space and isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

If $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, does it mean that $V$ is also isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$?
I am having a hard time trying to picture this. I was wondering if someone could explain this to me.

Comment: Just map the finite basis set to any basis set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$ and extend linearly to whole space. This map then should be an isomorphism. we can do this becase we know the space is finite dimensional.

Comment: If it's a finite-dimensional *real* vector space, then yes.

Comment: The answer is no. A simple counter example is the vector space $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ where  $\mathbb{F}_2 = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $V$ have dimension $n$ over $\Bbb R$, say with basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$. Define a map $f:V\to\Bbb R^n$ by

$$f(a_1v_1+\dots+a_nv_n)=(a_1,\dots,a_n).$$

I encourage you to check for yourself that this is linear, injective and surjective.